# Swift bluetooth le, write message and wait for response

Tags: swift, asynchronous, bluetooth, closures, core-bluetooth

Application can currently write a message,

```
// Write call 
peripheral.writeValue(messageToData, for: charac, type: .withResponse)

// Which calls
public func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didWriteValueFor 
characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
    if error != nil {
        print("messagesent")
    }
}
```

Also when the characteristic has been set up for the peripheral I've set the notification to true

```
peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
```

When I sent a write message I get a response from the bluetooth device going "OK" or "ERR" which is triggered through the didUpdateValueFor peripheral delegate method.

So the app can write and read responses from my device. However I want to be able to create a function that write the message and wait or checks for a response that is "OK" or "ERR". All the CORE BLuetooth functions can use my own protocol delegates if required.

I've been looking at something like:

```
func writeAndCheckResponse(message: String){
// Write to device
bluetooth.writeToPeripheral(message: "Test", peripheral: bluetooth.connectedDevice!, writeCharacteristic: bluetooth.characteristic!)
// need to add a way to check whether a notification has been recevied and that the message has been written
}
```

I've thought about using callback closures or DispatchGroup but since the swift Bluetooth is asynchronous I'm not exactly sure how to carry this out.

Comment: I did it by implementing Dispatcher which executes request-response commands serially using fifo queue. It takes care about request timeout and response timeout. On request you append it to queue. And on didWriteValueFor your bluetooth service passes response to Dispatcher and it executes next request in queue.